# what is the different between Kotlin File/Class and Kotlin Script

Tags: java, kotlin, android-dialogfragment

I discovering the programming language **kotlin** for some weeks, and I always start with new **File/Class**, and I've noticed lately to **kotlin** **Script** in the menu and I ask now what's different between the **Script** and the normal **File** in **kotlin**

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In a Kotlin source `*.kt` file, you can place top-level declarations, such as types and top-level functions and properties, but not code statements that are not nested into some declarations.

A Kotlin Script `*.kts` file, on contrary, contains code statements on the top level without any nesting. These statements are an equivalent of a `main` function. It is allowed to contain types, too, but with some limitations similar to those placed on nested type declarations.

Comment: Thanks this answer gave me idea about the Subject.

Comment: Is there a way to find out what the limitations on Kotlin scripts are? I'm bumping up against some "Expression is inaccessible from a nested class" errors in a kts file and would like to know if it's me or Kotlin.

Comment: For simplicity, I would add that the content of a `*.kts` file is *the actual body* of the main function.

Comment: Are there any resources to learn more about this topic? Anything is welcome

Comment: @MrCreed, on scripting in general, see https://kotlinlang.org/docs/custom-script-deps-tutorial.html#what-s-next